# Historical pronunciations

Tags: pronunciation, orthography

Is there a unified resource that gives the pronunciation of an English word according to how those most responsible for establishing its current spelling would have pronounced it?

Comment: How do you decide who's most responsible? We can assign the blame for certain spelling changes, like the loss of the U in "colo(u)r", but many changes are less purposeful than this.

Comment: And from that you can sometimes get where they came from and link to other changes in those dialects (of which there were hundreds, several every county).

Comment: I'm interested in when different spellings indicate differences in original pronunciation, like the meat-meet merger, and when they do not. Conversely, I'm interested in when similar spelling indicates similar original pronunciation, even if the modern pronunciations have diverged. That's all.

Comment: Noah Webster reformed English spelling significantly in the 19th century. So you're essentially asking how Webster would have pronounced everything.

Comment: Can you clarify '…  its current spelling'? Did you mean 'historical' or perhaps 'contemporary' spelling? How could the 'current' spelling matter

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I just meant the spelling used today. Consider two words like "meet" and "meat." That is how they are spelled today, and today they are homophones in most regions, but unless I'm mistaken, their difference in spelling reflects the fact that they were not homophones in older English. I am trying to determine how consistent English spelling is when you take into account historical pronunciations.

Comment: Any consistency in English spelling is largely a modern phenomenon Shakespeare is sometimes said to have spelled his own name six different ways - or should that be spelt? Bill the Quill died hardly 400 years ago and Webster came about half way since.

I think it was a modern Webster that taught me many if not most of today's 'Americanisms' are as likely to be Anglicisms; '…ire/yre' and '…or/our' et al were still equally common in Britain in colonial times and what's now seen as US American may even have been more prevalent - so different modern spelling from a common source.